# iPython Seaborn: How to fix pointplot() got multiple values for argument 'data'

Tags: python, seaborn

I am having this kind of error when I run seaborn in Jupyter Notebook. Please see below code snippet:

```
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,6))
    miss_previous_application = pd.DataFrame((previous_application.isnull().sum())*100/previous_application.shape[0]).reset_index()
    miss_previous_application["type"] = "previous_application"
    ax = sns.pointplot("index",0,data=miss_previous_application,hue="type")
    plt.xticks(rotation =90,fontsize =7)
    plt.title("Percentage of Missing values in previous_application")
    plt.ylabel("PERCENTAGE")
    plt.xlabel("COLUMNS")
    ax.set_facecolor("k")
    fig.set_facecolor("lightgrey")
```

Below is the error encountered:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-f0d92c128e6a> in <module>
      2 miss_previous_application = pd.DataFrame((previous_application.isnull().sum())*100/previous_application.shape[0]).reset_index()
      3 miss_previous_application["type"] = "previous_application"
----> 4 ax = sns.pointplot("index",0,data=miss_previous_application,hue="type")
      5 plt.xticks(rotation =90,fontsize =7)
      6 plt.title("Percentage of Missing values in previous_application")

TypeError: pointplot() got multiple values for argument 'data'

<Figure size 1296x432 with 0 Axes>
```

Comment: The error is correct.  The first parameter to `pointplot`, where you have `"index"`, is the `data`.  Please check the documentation.  If that is supposed to be the label, then specify `label="index"`.  I don't know what your `0` is supposed to be.

Comment: @TimRoberts I did. However, it returns this error: `File "<ipython-input-11-c316f04149af>", line 4
    ax = sns.pointplot(label="index",0,data=miss_previous_application,hue="type")
                                     ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument`

Comment: Right.  That's what I said.  I don't know what parameter you intended the `0` to be, but it will need to have a name as well.

Comment: Maybe `sns.pointplot(x="index",y=0,data=..., ...)`?